# Overview of the fee structure and strategy to minimize fees?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

1. What are the current rules regarding transaction fees?
2. What transactions are broadcasted by the QT-Client?
3. How to the big pools act - what kind of transactions do say include in their blocks?

The background of the question: We are building a site where people can deposit bitcoins. Interact with the site to increase or decrease their balance and finally cash out to a Bitcoin address. (Like any Exchange, oder Just-Dice)

Obviously, we want to pay as little transaction fees as possible but still have reliable cash outs.

What is the best strategy to minimize fees?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can some exchanges/services afford to pay for customers transaction fees?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17271/5406), [How do faucets/micropayment-based services avoid/minimize transaction fees?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/11748/5406)

Comment: related: [Not relaying non-standard transactions](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/18638/5406), [Do transactions and blocks get relayed even if a node believes them to be invalid?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4680/5406)

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. Please see [about] or [Ask] for more information. Please feel free to edit this post to narrow it down to the most important question and/or re-post any questions by themselves that remain.